# Sincronismo de dados PHP com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Quando a página é carregada através da URL `index.php?num=58` inicialmente a página `autosalvar.php` não reconhece o valor do input `name="num-edit"` (que contém o número **58**), contudo ao passar pelo intervalo de tempo de 2 segundos o valor **58** é capturado.

Obs.: preciso setar o valor (clicando no *link* correspondente ao ID) e permanecer na `index.php`, pois é nela que é realizado o autosave.

**header.php**

```
$(function () {

  /* Captura o 1º parâmetro passado pela URL */
  var valor_num = /num=([^&]+)/.exec(window.location.href)[1];
  $("[name='num-edit']").attr('value', valor_num);

  /* Autopreencher os campos do formulário com dados do BD */
  $.post("actions/autosalvar.php", function (data) {
    $("[name='id-cliente']").attr('value', data.id_cliente);
    $("[name='cliente']").attr('value', data.cliente);
  }, "json");

  /* Passar dados do formulário a cada 2 segundos para página PHP */
  setInterval(function () {           
    var dados = $('#meu_form').serializeObject();

    $.post("actions/autosalvar.php", {'meus_dados': dados}).done(function(data) {
    });

  }, 2000);

});
```

**index.php:**

```
<form name="meu_form" id="meu_form" novalidate="novalidate">
  <!-- Campo oculto para pegar ID do cliente  -->
  <input type="number" hidden name="num-edit" />

  <?php
  foreach($resultado_query as $res){      
    $id = $res['id'];
  ?>
  <!-- Setar ID na URL -->
  <a href="index.php?num=<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <?php } ?>
</form>
```

**autosalvar.php:**

```
/* Pegar ID para realizar consulta no BD */
$num = &$_POST['meus_dados']['num-edit'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi do seu código cada vez que você clica no no LINK é executado um postback e recarrega a página ...

Tente utilizar o javascript para fazer isso.

Crie um ID para o seu Link e use no JavaScript assim:

```
$("#link").on("click", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
 var dados = $('#meu_form').serializeObject();

    $.post("actions/autosalvar.php", {'meus_dados': dados}).done(function(data) {
      //executado com sucesso
    });
});
```

Isso vai evitar que quando clicar no link ele mude de página...

Funcionou?

```
function atualizarDados() { 
var dados = $('#meu_form').serializeObject(); $.post("actions/autosalvar.php", {'meus_dados': dados})
.done(function(data) { //executado com sucesso }); 
}; 

setInterval(atualizarDados, 2000);
```

Comment: Olá @HebertJunior, não funcionou. O autosave deve ser executado a cada 2 segundos e não ao clicar no _link_...

Comment: Hebert, poderíamos continuar via chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54076/sincronismo-de-dados-php-com-javascript

Answer (score 1):

No JS, apenas após o retorno do primeiro post você inicia a checagem a cada 2 segundos. Então você coloca um inicializador chamado "loopcheck()" dentro do retorno do post, veja como ficou abaixo:

```
$(function () {
  /* Captura o 1º parâmetro passado pela URL */
  var valor_num = /num=([^&]+)/.exec(window.location.href)[1];
  $("[name='num-edit']").attr('value', valor_num);

  /* Autopreencher os campos do formulário com dados do BD */
  $.post("actions/autosalvar.php", function (data) {
    $("[name='id-cliente']").attr('value', data.id_cliente);
    $("[name='cliente']").attr('value', data.cliente);
    loopcheck();
  }, "json");
});
function loopcheck(){/* Passar dados do formulário a cada 2 segundos para página PHP */
  setInterval(function () {
    var dados = $('#meu_form').serializeObject();
    $.post("actions/autosalvar.php", {'meus_dados':dados}).done(function(data) {

    });
  }, 2000);
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Boa sorte!

Comment: O JS continua pegando o valor "vazio" do `input` na primeira chamada da página `autosalvar.php`.

Comment: Fábio, podemos continuar a discussão via chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54076/sincronismo-de-dados-php-com-javascript